# Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 is required

Tags: .net

unfortunately I uninstall Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 and when i am trying to re install it gives an error. Please help me to solve it. How con I solve it ?

Comment: I think offtopic. But try to extend question by details of error. It could help a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try the one showed in the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot]